# Dual Linear Program of the Densest-Subset Problem

Tags: graphs, linear-programming

In the densest-subset problem, given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, the goal is to
maximise the “edge-density” ratio $|E(S)|/|S|$
over all non-empty sets $S ⊆ V$ , where $E(S)$ denotes the
set of edges whose both endpoints lie in $S$.

The Primal LP is of the form:

\begin{align}
\max & \sum_{e \in E} y_e \\
\text{s.t.} \; & y_e \leq x_u,x_v \text{ for all } e = (u,v) \in E, \\
&\sum_{v \in V} x_v = 1, \\
&y_e,x_v \ge 0 \text{ for all } v \in V, e \in E.
\end{align}

I'm trying to understand why the dual is as follows:

\begin{align}
\min\; & w \\
s.t.\; & z_{u,e} + z_{v,e} \ge 1 \text{ for all } e = (u,v) \in E, \\
& \sum_{e;\, e \text{ incident to } v} z_{v,e} \le w \text{ for all } v \in V, \\
& z_{v,e} \text{ for all } v \in V, e \in E.
\end{align}

I've never seen an LP before where the constants we multiply the primal by happen to correspond to both the vertices and the edges of the graph at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried computing the dual? What did you get?